# Reject binary on itunes connect after 09.09.2014

Tags: app-store-connect

On new iTunes connect I cannot find the way of rejecting binary. I mean uploading new build without increasing bundle version. Is it possible?

Comment: Having the same issue. Adding new screenshots seemed to give me the ability to change which build I could use, but then hitting 'Save' didn't work. Would love to know the answer.

Comment: Same here. Couldn't figure out the Reject button so far.

Answer (score 1):

To reject the build you can always download the "iTunes Connect Mobile" iOS app and reject the binary in the iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a possible fix, but I'm not totally sure. I updated my computer from Mavericks to the Yosemite beta, went into Safari menu -> Clear History and Website data. Then I restarted my computer. After that, I was able to reject my app and submit screenshots.

Of course, it could just be that Apple has updated iTunes Connect to work now, and the timing was just coincidental, so maybe try without updating to Yosemite first if you can avoid it.

Let me know if that works for you :)