# Error Uploading Screenshots to new iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot, uploading

I've been experiencing this issue for two days, since the new iTunes Connect became avaiable.

When adding a new screenshot, at first, I was receiving the error:

> Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem
> persists, contact us.

Inspecting the element in browser, in the console i could see that they got a server error:

> We've got a server error... 500

But yesterday, the error changed. The server was responding `SUCCESS`, but a new error appeared when trying to upload any screenshot:

> Failed to create a screenshot for Screenshots for 4-inch iPhone 5 and
> iPod touch (5th generation) Retina display (error for 4-inch upload)

I'm sure my image types/sizes are ok.

Today, I'm back to the server error...

Apple responded my thread with them today, but to ask for additional information such as screenshots and the source code of the page.

Anyone else having this issue? Anyone got the answers from Apple?

---

Screenshot of inspecting element in Safari:

[image: Safari screenshot showing error messages as described in the text]

Comment: Having this issue as well. Please let me know if you find a fix.

Comment: For the new Itunes, the new uploader says to upgrade your OS and Safari in order to upload video previews. Recently this seems to be true for screenshots as well. The drag and drop works fine on Chrome, though.

Comment: I added the pictures in Safari instead of Chrome/Firefox and it worked fine. Tried all the renaming suggesting first, those did not work for me.

Comment: Still happening intermittently, even in Safari.

Answer (score 19):

I met the same problem. The solution for me is just avoiding to use the default name (i.e. iOS Simulator Screen Shot ********), simply rename the screenshots as "1.png, 2.png..." and it should be OK now.

Comment: This. I had the same problem. Removed the spaces from the file names, and everything worked well. Geeze, Apple!

Answer (score 11):

Found the solution, you have to rename your screenshot to **remove any accent** in it. Then the upload will work.

Comment: didn't work here =/

still getting the `Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us.` error

Comment: I worked after rename those images to 01.png - 05.png

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I tried renaming it to 01.png and it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 9):

I had an error where none of the uploaded images in iTunes Connect would generate (or preview).

Turned out to be a browser incompatibility. Switched to Safari and the uploaded worked just fine.

Comment: Safari and Chrome didn't work for me. Switched to Firefox and worked.

Answer (score 5):

I posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817485/1695900), but I was able to fix my problems by doing the following:

> I think I've found a possible fix, but I'm not totally sure. I updated
>   my computer from Mavericks to the Yosemite beta, went into Safari menu
>   -> Clear History and Website data. Then I restarted my computer. After that, I was able to reject my app and submit screenshots.
>
> Of course, it could just be that Apple has updated iTunes Connect to
>   work now, and the timing was just coincidental, so maybe try without
>   updating to Yosemite first if you can avoid it.
>
> Let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: You were having the same issues with the screenshots ? I'm still getting the 'your app information could not be saved'... I will try what you said and install Yosemite tomorrow

Comment: Yeah I couldn't update screenshots or save anything, like if I updated the description of the app it wouldn't even save. Try clearing website data and restarting before you do the beta—hopefully it will save you some time. Also, it didn't work right away when I updated to Yosemite; it took like 12 hours before it would work properly after I updated, cleared website data etc.

Comment: It does not seem to be the Beta that solved your issue, like you said... And I've already tried to upload in a windows pc and even on iOS, with several browsers, and cleaning all data from them... Strange error...

Comment: Added a screenshot of my safari's inspecting element when error occurs

Comment: Hmm your error might be different to mine. From memory, I don't think I got a 500 server error, just a validation error when I inspected the `Object` that is returned. As NSZombie said below, I'd double check to see if you App Name, Description, Screenshots, or anything that you are submitting has only English characters. If that fixes the problem, you can always change it back once Apple has pushed a fix.

Comment: I finally got mine done after running into the same problem. Changed all the filenames to remove spaces, dots (except the file suffix) and anything non-ASCII. That didn't work. So then I only uploaded one screen size (3.5 inch, 4 inch, 4.7 inch etc) at a time and hit "Save" between each in Safari. That worked for the images but I still ran into some other validation errors so switched back and forth between Chrome and Safari for the rest.

Comment: Clearing browsing history worked for me! :D Thanks! Apple really has to take iTunes Connect more seriously...

Comment: This solution worked for me too. I just cleared the history for today in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

After facing similar issue 2 days continuously i found solution, Following things you should check step by step before uploading screenshots to iTunes.

**1) iTunes Connect Screenshots Sizes for all iPhones (As per Apple Documentation)** -

**72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format**

- iPhone 3+4 (3.5 Inch)

  **Any of the following sizes:**

  640 x 920 pixels for hi-res portrait (without status bar) minimum

  640 x 960 pixels for hi-res portrait (full screen) maximum

  960 x 600 pixels for hi-res landscape (without status bar) minimum

  960 x 640 pixels for hi-res landscape (full screen) maximum
- iPhone 5 (4 Inch)

  **Any of the following sizes**

  640 x 1096 pixels for portrait (without status bar) minimum

  640 x 1136 pixels for portrait (full screen) maximum

  1136 x 600 pixels for landscape (without status bar) minimum

  1136 x 640 pixels for landscape (full screen) minimum
- iPhone 6 (4.7 Inch)

  750 x 1334 pixels for hi-res portrait

  1334 x 750 pixels for hi-res landscape
- iPhone 6 Plus (5.5 Inch)

  1242 x 2208 pixels for hi-res portrait

  2208 x 1242 pixels for hi-res landscape

**2)Avoid default naming convention of simulator.**

- Keep different names for each different set of images.
- say for 4 inch you have 4 different images, keep each image name  different.
- Again it should be different for 4.7 inch so on.

**3) Either safari or chrome whatever it may be Clear cookies, history and website data before uploading images.**
 (I stuck lot of time in this because of browser history and and cookies)

Comment: For videos, check this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10 (App Preview Specification). I had a problem that the data rate was not between 10-12  mbps

Comment: Thanks, BTW it was 2 years back :)

Comment: You had the best answer which helped me figure out my issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. Tried Chrome instead of Safari and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem, also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733107/new-itunes-connect-wont-save-after-screenshots-are-added), using chrome on windows, used "clear browser history" on the last hour and this fixed the problem. Seems to be a bad cookie, which means clearing cookies or switching browsers will solve the problems very similarly.

Answer (score 2):

I´ve solved it by using Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was we had multiple users with the same app record open on iTunes Connect at the same time. But fist I thought solved by changing safari to chrome... but after few minutes it starts showing same warning again...

I solved it by getting everyone to **log out** while I was logged in and uploaded the screenshots :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be too late to this party, but I have faced the same issues for the past several hours and here's what worked for me.

NOTE: use images without transparency (JPG) and keep the names simple like 1.jpg 2.jpg. Make sure that all the file names are unique.

1. log out, clear cookies, log in, and remove all images from all devices. Make sure you only have one tab open.
2. upload the images one by one per device. No DnD and no multiple uploads.
3. once the images are uploaded per device, right click on the image and view its url. Copy the url and open the url in another tab. You should see the image.
4. refresh the page after 2 minutes and make sure that you can click on the image thumbnails and see all the images you just uploaded per device.
5. repeat steps 1 to 3 for all other devices.

Don't know why, but this somehow this worked for me. Just submitted my app for review after 5 hours of redoing the same thing over and over again until I tried the steps above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just wait 30 minutes to 1 hour and try it again.